# Is $f_n$ continuous and does it converge pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&-1 &&\text{for $x \in [-1,-1/n]$}\\
&nx&&\text{for $x \in (-1/n,1/n)$}\\
&1&&\text{for $x \in [1/n,1]$}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
I need to show that $f_n$ is continuous, and that it converges point-wise to some function.
For continuity, I'm not sure how to pick my $\delta$. For the next part, It seems that the sequence converges to $0$ when $x = 0$, and $-1$ for the left side of the interval, and $1$ for the right side. I just can't seem to understand how to formalize this. Any help?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [the pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma). Your function is a glueing of three continuous functions. As long they can be extended to closure of their domains **and** they coincide on that closure (and they do in your case) then the glueing has to be continuous.

Comment: If $x\ne 0$ then $|x|>1/n $ for all but finitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ so for all but finitely many $n\in \Bbb  N$ we have $f_n(x)=x/|x|$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=x/|x|.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: verify that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq n|x-y|$ for all $n$ and $x$. This is obvious if $x$ and $y$ are both $< -\frac  1 n$, both $ > \frac  1 n$ or both are between $-\frac  1 n$ and $ \frac  1 n$. Suppose $x$ is between $-\frac  1 n$ and $ \frac  1 n$ and $y >\frac  1 n$. Then we have to show $1-nx \leq n(y-x)$ which is easy. I will let you handle the other cases. For poitwise limit you have to observe that for any given $x\neq 0$ either $x >\frac 1 n$ or $x < -\frac 1 n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

For continuity, you really need to check only points $x=\pm\frac{1}{n}$, and for that you need to check the one-sided limits of the function from both sides, which are given by the formulas on the both sides of these points.

To formalize finding the limit:

For $x=0$:
$$f_n(0) = n\cdot 0 = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  0 = 0 $$
For $x<0$:
$$ f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} nx & \text{for }n < -\frac{1}{x} \\ -1 & \text{for } n\ge -\frac{1}{x}\end{array}\right. \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1) = -1$$
For $x>0$:
$$ f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} nx & \text{for }n < \frac{1}{x} \\ 1 & \text{for } n\ge \frac{1}{x}\end{array}\right. \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1 = 1$$